# new and delete[] are worse than malloc and free? (c++ / VS2012)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

OK, so, I wrote some code to check, how much memory is available at runtime. A whole (minimal) cpp file is below.

**NOTE: The code is not perfect and not best practice, but I hope that you can focus on the memory management rather than the code.**

What it does (part I):

- (1) Allocate as much memory as possible in one
  block. Clear that memory
- (2) Allocate as many medium sized blocks
  (16MB) as possible. Clear that memory.

--> This works fine

What it does (part II):

- (1) Allocate as much memory as possible in one block. Clear that memory
- (2) Allocate as many tiny blocks (16kb) as possible. Clear that memory.

--> This behaves weird!

The problem is: If I repeat that, I can only allocate 522kb for the secons run onward ---> ?

It does not happen, if the allocated blocks have e.g. 16MB of size.

Do you have any ideas, why this happens?

```
// AvailableMemoryTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    auto determineMaxAvailableMemoryBlock = []( void ) -> int
    {
        int nBytes = std::numeric_limits< int >::max();

        while ( true )
        {
            try
            {
                std::vector< char >vec( nBytes );
                break;
            }
            catch ( std::exception& ex )
            {
                nBytes = static_cast< int >( nBytes * 0.99 );
            }
        }
        return nBytes;
    };

    auto determineMaxAvailableMemoryFragmented = []( int nBlockSize ) -> int
    {

        int nBytes = 0;

        std::list< std::vector< char > > listBlocks;

        while ( true )
        {
            try
            {
                listBlocks.push_back( std::vector< char >( nBlockSize ) );
                nBytes += nBlockSize;
            }
            catch ( std::exception& ex )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return nBytes;
    };


    std::cout << "Test with large memory blocks (16MB):\n";
    for ( int k = 0; k < 5; k++ )
    {
        std::cout << "run #" << k << "   max  mem block          = " << determineMaxAvailableMemoryBlock() / 1024.0 / 1024.0 << "MB\n";
        std::cout << "run #" << k << "   frag mem blocks of 16MB = " << determineMaxAvailableMemoryFragmented( 16*1024*1024 ) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 << "MB\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
    } // for_k
    

    std::cout << "Test with small memory blocks (16k):\n";
    for ( int k = 0; k < 5; k++ )
    {
        std::cout << "run #" << k << "   max  mem block          = " << determineMaxAvailableMemoryBlock() / 1024.0 / 1024.0 << "MB\n";
        std::cout << "run #" << k << "   frag mem blocks of 16k  = " << determineMaxAvailableMemoryFragmented( 16*1024 ) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 << "MB\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
    } // for_k

    std::cin.get();


    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT with large memory blocks (this works fine)

```
Test with large memory blocks (16MB):
run #0   max  mem block          = 1023.67MB     OK
run #0   frag mem blocks of 16MB = 1952MB        OK

run #1   max  mem block          = 1023.67MB     OK
run #1   frag mem blocks of 16MB = 1952MB        OK

run #2   max  mem block          = 1023.67MB     OK
run #2   frag mem blocks of 16MB = 1952MB        OK

run #3   max  mem block          = 1023.67MB     OK
run #3   frag mem blocks of 16MB = 1952MB        OK

run #4   max  mem block          = 1023.67MB     OK
run #4   frag mem blocks of 16MB = 1952MB        OK
```

OUTPUT with small memory blocks (memory allocation is weird from the second run onwards)

```
Test with small memory blocks (16k):
run #0   max  mem block          = 1023.67MB     OK
run #0   frag mem blocks of 16k  = 1991.06MB     OK

run #1   max  mem block          = 0.493021MB    ???
run #1   frag mem blocks of 16k  = 1991.34MB     OK

run #2   max  mem block          = 0.493021MB    ???
run #2   frag mem blocks of 16k  = 1991.33MB     OK

run #3   max  mem block          = 0.493021MB    ???
run #3   frag mem blocks of 16k  = 1991.33MB     OK

run #4   max  mem block          = 0.493021MB    ???
run #4   frag mem blocks of 16k  = 1991.33MB     OK
```

**UPDATE:**

This happels as well with new and delete[] instead of STL's internal memory allocation.

**UPDATE:**

It works for 64 bit (I limited the memory that both functions are allowed to allocate to 12GB). Really weird. Here is an image of that version's RAM usage:

[image: RAM usage]

**UPDATE:**
It works with malloc and free, but not with new and delete[] (or STL as described above)

Comment: One possibility: heap managers tend to have various sections of the heap for different block sizes. It might be that that when you first fill everything with small blocks, one of the small block heap areas takes over everything, as is kept around for future allocations.

Comment: OK, but why does it keep the memory instead of giving it the next allocation? It's not in use anymore...

Comment: Why are you creating `std::vector<char>` instead of the more direct methods (`new char[]` or `malloc`)?

Comment: @sfstewman: Why not? This is the simplest way, and it's functionally equivalent to your hacky, low-level, error-prone methods. For example, this approach avoids any worry that the allocated blocks may be leaked. The OP has done this right.

Comment: This is most likely the result of fragmentation.  Not all heap implementations manage fragmentation well.  When you allocate small chunks and return them to the heap, they may not be coalesced, which effectively reduces usable memory.  You may want to try using a different heap implementation like [`tcmalloc`](https://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tcmalloc.html) and see if you get different results.

Comment: any further ideas? malloc/free should really fulfill their basic jobs?!??

Comment: What happens if you call your 16k before your 16M test?

Comment: @IceArdor Same thing...

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comment above, this is most likely a heap [fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)#External_fragmentation) issue.  The heap will maintain lists of different sized chunks to satisfy different memory requests.  Larger memory chunks are broken into smaller chunks for smaller memory requests to avoid wasting the difference between the chunk size and request size, which reduces the number of larger chunks.  So, when a larger chunk is requested, the heap may not have enough large chunks to satisfy the request.

Fragmentation is a major issue with heap implementations since it effectively reduces usable memory.  However, some heap implementations are able to coalesce smaller chunks back into larger chunks, and are better able to satisfy large requests even after a number of smaller requests.

I ran your above code, very slightly modified, using glibc's `malloc` (`ptmalloc`) and I got the following results...

```
Test with large memory blocks (16MB):
run #0   max  mem block          = 2048MB
run #0   frag mem blocks of 16MB = 2032MB

run #1   max  mem block          = 2048MB
run #1   frag mem blocks of 16MB = 2032MB

run #2   max  mem block          = 2048MB
run #2   frag mem blocks of 16MB = 2032MB

run #3   max  mem block          = 2048MB
run #3   frag mem blocks of 16MB = 2032MB

run #4   max  mem block          = 2048MB
run #4   frag mem blocks of 16MB = 2032MB

Test with small memory blocks (16k):
run #0   max  mem block          = 2048MB
run #0   frag mem blocks of 16k  = 2047.98MB

run #1   max  mem block          = 2048MB
run #1   frag mem blocks of 16k  = 2047.98MB

run #2   max  mem block          = 2048MB
run #2   frag mem blocks of 16k  = 2047.98MB

run #3   max  mem block          = 2048MB
run #3   frag mem blocks of 16k  = 2047.98MB

run #4   max  mem block          = 2048MB
run #4   frag mem blocks of 16k  = 2047.98MB
```

So, `ptmalloc` at least seems to handle fragmentation well for this particular scenario.

Comment: Fragmentation means, if I allocate the blocks ABCDE, then delete ACE, we have xBxDx and I can't allocate a block larger than A, C or E. But what I'm doing is that I dele ALL blocks, So I should get the memory as xxxxx (completely empty) and reallocation should work!!!

Comment: The problem is that the heaps don't necessarily know that ABCDE are contiguous.  So, for example if ABCDE gets split into A, B, C, D, and E.  If A gets returned and then B, the heap doesn't necessarily know B is the address after A (unless the heap is designed to like `ptmalloc` or [`tcmalloc`](https://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tcmalloc.html).  Can you try linking to `tcmalloc`?  According to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-perftools/iYKiTSZJeFY), all you should need to do is link to `tcmalloc` before MSVCRT.

Comment: "The problem is that the heaps don't necessarily know that ABCDE are contiguous." That would be a showstopper bug in a heap implementation, making it unusable for any real work.

Comment: Not all heap implementations aggressively merge contiguous chunks or even merge contiguous chunks at all.  The first, and only I know of, to use a radix tree to maintain spans is `tcmalloc`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're running 32bit code for some reason?

Best guess: your `malloc` implementation leaves bookkeeping data scattered everywhere in memory after freeing, when the allocations were small.  Malloc implementations typically use different allocation strategies for small vs. large allocations, so it's not unreasonable that the bookkeeping info could be in different places.

On Unix, small allocations are usually done with `brk`, while large allocations are done with `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)`.  `_tmain` and `stdafx.h` means you're testing on Windows, so IDK about how that malloc works under the hood.

Comment: Your first sentence is strange. You appear to imply that it's somehow unusual or bizarre to run 32-bit code. Can you explain that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Even current Atom CPUs support 64bit mode.  x86-32 has been obsolete for years.  The extra registers and register-call ABI are worth about 10 to 15% performance on typical code.  If you're writing new code, it should be 64bit.  If you're going to make a 32bit version at all, it's just for supporting users with really bad hardware.

Comment: Good grief open your mind; we're not all programming brand new commodity hardware for the consumer market. Where do you think _infrastructure_ comes from?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Sure, there are reasons for making 32bit binaries.  IMO the "default" should be 64bit, though.

Comment: I'll check the 64 bit version and I'll post the update... hoever... this really shouldn't matter. My system should be able to reallocate memory!

Comment: @S.H: yeah, there's clearly something undesirable about the malloc you're using for your 32bit build.  (Presumably the default Visual C++ malloc.)  A 64bit build of the same test program will exhaust virtual memory before hitting a problem.  My point was that 64bit code wouldn't have a close-to-exhausting-address-space issue in the first place.  You only need to deal with this headache if you need a rock-solid 32bit version of your software.  This might or might not be the case.

Comment: This is getting weirder and weirder... I works for 64bit (I limited the max allocatable space to 12GB). I'll update this above.

Comment: @S.H: That's what I'd expect; I don't think it sounds weird at all.  With nearly unlimited address space, 64bit malloc doesn't need to merge 16k blocks back into big blocks it can return as a big single allocation.  It can instead just return a big contiguous block from somewhere else in the vast 64bit address space.  64bit programs never come anywhere near running out of virtual address space.  It looks like your compiler's default allocator doesn't do very well on this specific corner case that's only relevant for 32bit code.